# How to reject a file upload in a web server before it is uploaded

Tags: php, file-upload

When a POST request is sent to a web server containing a file, the targeting PHP file starts executing once the upload is completed. I'm looking for a way to reject a file upload before it is uploaded. And I'm not expecting any information of the file to be available, just the fact that a file is going to be uploaded and the HTTP headers are enough for me to decide whether to reject it or not.

I believe this is not possible using PHP in an ordinary manner. I'm hoping web servers would provide a chance so I can give them a script (CLI) to manage this!? And I'm not using shared hosting.

**[UPDATE]**

In case I'm not clear, I'm looking for a server side solution!

**[UPDATE]**

What I want to do is already done in PHP in case the file being uploaded is too large. PHP checks the HTTP header `Content-length` to verify if the size of file is greater than `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini. I would like to do the same check differently, perhaps using the session id.

Comment: You would need to use an event listener (JS/jQuery) and maybe a sprinkle of Ajax ;-) along with conditional statements.

Comment: You'll have to use a front-end language for that like JavaScript

Comment: You should use something client-side (JS) to do this.

Comment: As per your edit/update, can't be done server-side, far as I know. What risks in happening (it can be done but) is that the upload would still take effect, and using a conditional statement, reject it. But then you're still faced with the file(s) being uploaded, and nobody likes to upload for nothing. ;-) You can't do away without some form of JS interaction; "again", far as I know.

Comment: If you do this server side only, the client has no way of knowing that, and would thus continue uploading the file anyway.

Comment: It might be impossible for now, but it shouldn't be as I can simply do this if I'm coding the web server myself. And browser won't be uploading once I reject the file upload, since the socket will be closed after the request headers are sent (in case of rejection).

Comment: Well, if you already know the answer, why ask us?

Comment: I'm saying if I'm making a web server I can do this simply. I'm asking this question to see if the popular web servers provide a solution for this problem.

Comment: Ah, well I for one don't know the method they use. There stands to be some form of "event listener" yet I wouldn't leave JS out of the equation.

Comment: I have a little experience with socket programming and HTTP protocol. Files are sent in HTTP protocol in a multi-part manner, which means it is pretty easy to know when headers are done and file parts are starting. I was hoping a plugin architecture would let me introduce a CLI PHP script to the web server so it is executed before the files are sent so I can close the socket and reject the file upload.

Comment: That sounds promising, however it's beyond the scope of my knowledge.